# Worm found inside of wahoo

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, parasitology

A fisherman from Hawaii wrote the following:

> This Fat juicy worm lives inside of every [Wahoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahoo) that I catch. Inside
>   the stomach. Right at the junction to the intestines. Sometimes there
>   are two.

What is this parasite?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is [Giant Stomach Worm](http://www.sealifebase.org/summary/Hirudinella-ventricosa.html) (*Hirudinella Ventricosa*).

It is a platyhelmith parasitic to Wahoo fish, feeding on its blood and found inside the stomach. It makes 98% of Wahoo's parasitic infections.

> It is a fleshy worm that varies in size and shape; with extended worms the size of a mans finger and contracted ones about the size of a walnut.

It requires two hosts to complete its lifecycle; a snail and a wahoo fish.

A [picture](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/ngm/0702/feature4/gallery15.html) from National Geographic Society

Source: [lahaina news](http://lahainanews.com/page/content.detail/id/509508/Parasite-found-in-most-ono.html?nav=21)

Note: A youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r2l-UbYvOU) shows this worm moving.